# Query Ms Access by date c# winform data gridview

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I'm using the following code to fill a datagridview with a dataadapter from a MS Access database, it does not give any error, but will not return any value

here is the code

```
 private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User Id=;Password=;Data Source=TS-POS.accdb");
        conn.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT InvoiceNo, DayDate, Gross, Net, Staff FROM GrossSales Where DayDate = #" + dateFrom.Value.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy") + "#;", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        dataGridView2.Columns["InvoiceNo"].HeaderText = "رقم الفاتورة";
        dataGridView2.Columns["InvoiceNo"].Width = 150;
        dataGridView2.Columns["DayDate"].HeaderText = " التاريخ";
        dataGridView2.Columns["DayDate"].Width = 350;
        dataGridView2.Columns["Gross"].HeaderText = "الإجمالي";
        dataGridView2.Columns["Gross"].Width = 150;
        dataGridView2.Columns["Net"].HeaderText = " الصافي";
        dataGridView2.Columns["Net"].Width = 150;
        dataGridView2.Columns["Staff"].HeaderText = " الموظف";
        dataGridView2.Columns["Staff"].Width = 150;
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Here is how it appears in the database

[image]

Comment: So, are there rows in the datatable in ds after the fill? Also why set columns after setting the datasource?

Comment: @TaW No, when the form is opened, it gets filled without using the Where daydate = condition.. but once I choose date and click search, it is empy - For the columns? it must be set before the Adapter query?

Comment: So the condition is either wrong or there are now fitting rows. Best __log out the actual sql string__ and play with it! (You may be missign the time component?) (( as for the columns: No, sorry I didn't read properly; you are just styling them; this is fine as it is))

Comment: The point is, I want to search all sales done on the chosen day, so why would I need the time component?

Comment: But you are comparing for equality, not for being less or larger. But it would depend on whether the db column contains a time..

Comment: should I use between 2 dates intead you mean?

Comment: If you only want that day, no. But do have a look at the sql string and also at the value..

Comment: @TaW, I've tried using the between and it worked, but there is one problem tho, it will not show today's sales, only previous dates when selected. I have to select like this for it to work DateFrom 19/05/2018 DateTo 20/05/2018
if I try to search today's sales DateFrom 20/05/2018 Date To 20/05/2018 it shows no data

Comment: You would write sth like `after date and smaller (date+1)` Note the Date&Time fileds do contain a time component in Access just liek DateTime in c#. Which is the reason of the problems. The normal way is to complare only the Date portion.. I believe there is a `JustDate` clause in Access. Or a `filed.DateValue` clause.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to make it show today's date automatically? like DayDate = Date/Time

Comment: `Date()` should return the current system date. To select only the date portion this should work: `DateValue([DayDate ]) = ..`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT InvoiceNo, DayDate, Gross, Net, Staff FROM GrossSales Where DayDate >= #" + dateFrom.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "# And DayDate < #" + dateFrom.Value.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#;", conn);
```